# Changing a Procedure to a View in Oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, cursor, view

Not sure if this is possible, but I'm trying to see if I can convert this procedure to become a view because we've been having trouble with drives not populating the table when the procedure is run.

I'm trying to understand someone else's code and because of the cursors, I'm not even sure we can change this procedure to a view.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
--This Procedure will interface drive information on a nightly basis--
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Procedure HEMA_DRIVE_AUTO IS

v_start_date               DATE     := trunc(sysdate) -30;      
v_end_date                 DATE     := trunc(sysdate);          
v_delete_stats_dt          DATE     := trunc(sysdate)-120;

v_total_registration_count NUMBER;
v_total_performed_count    NUMBER;
v_total_collected_count    NUMBER;
v_total_deferred_count     NUMBER;
v_total_qns_count          NUMBER;
v_existing_drive           NUMBER;
v_existing_performed       NUMBER;
v_maph_drive               NUMBER;

--This Cursor will collect the initial data
cursor c_drive_info is
  select dr.drive_id, dr.Start_time, dr.vehicle_id
    from drives dr
   --where dr.drive_id in(1605606);
   where trunc(dr.start_time) between v_start_date and v_end_date;

--This Cursor will be used to decode the Donation Types
cursor c_procedure_codes is
  select * from hema_donation_type_map hdt 
    where hdt.mobiles = 1 order by procedure_code_id;

--This Cursor will define the intentions but exclude theraputics inthe mapping
cursor c_intention is
  select rsa_motivation_id,hema_intent_id from hema_intent_map 
    where rsa_motivation_id <> 4 order by rsa_motivation_id;

   BEGIN
-- delete records older then 4 months
delete from hema_nightly h where trunc(h.drive_date) < v_delete_stats_dt;
commit;

FOR cur_drive IN c_drive_info LOOP

 delete from hema_nightly where drive_id = cur_drive.drive_id;
 commit;

 -- Loop by motivation/intention
 FOR cur_intent in c_intention LOOP

  -- Loop to get the procedure code data
  FOR cur_proc_code IN c_procedure_codes LOOP

    v_total_registration_count := 0;
    v_total_performed_count    := 0;
    v_total_collected_count    := 0;
    v_total_deferred_count     := 0;
    v_total_qns_count          := 0;
    v_maph_drive               := 0;


      -- get the count for all other procedures
      select count(1)
        into v_total_registration_count
        from registration r
       where r.drive_id = cur_drive.drive_id
         and r.donation_type_id = cur_proc_code.donation_type_id
         and r.motivation_id = cur_intent.rsa_motivation_id;

      --get the deferral count
      select count(unique(r.registration_id))
        into v_total_deferred_count
        from registration r
       where r.drive_id = cur_drive.drive_id
         and r.donation_type_id = cur_proc_code.donation_type_id
         and r.motivation_id = cur_intent.rsa_motivation_id
         and r.step_completed < 12
         and exists (select rsc.registration_id
                from reg_steps_completed rsc
               where rsc.registration_id = r.registration_id
                 and rsc.collection_step_id = 99);

      -- QNS count
      select count(unique(r.registration_id))
        into v_total_qns_count
        from registration r
       where r.drive_id = cur_drive.drive_id
         and r.step_completed < 12
         and not exists (select rsc.registration_id
                from reg_steps_completed rsc
               where rsc.registration_id = r.registration_id
                 and rsc.collection_step_id = 99)
         and r.donation_type_id = cur_proc_code.donation_type_id
         and r.motivation_id = cur_intent.rsa_motivation_id;

    -- performed count is the difference between total registrations and total deferrals.
    v_total_performed_count := v_total_registration_count -
                               (v_total_deferred_count +
                               v_total_qns_count);

    -- not calulatind yield so keep count the same
    v_total_collected_count := v_total_performed_count; 

    -- does this drive exist 
    select count(drive_id)
      into v_existing_drive
      from hema_nightly
     where drive_id = cur_drive.drive_id
       and procedure_id = cur_proc_code.procedure_code_id
       and intent = cur_intent.hema_intent_id;

    -- Is this an aph vehicle?
     select count(vehicle_id)
       into v_maph_drive
       from vehicles
      where veh_drive_type_uid = 2
        and vehicle_id = cur_drive.vehicle_id;

    if v_existing_drive > 0 then

      update hema_nightly
           set performed  = performed  + v_total_performed_count,
               collected  = collected  + v_total_collected_count,
               registered = registered + v_total_registration_count,
               deferrals  = deferrals  + v_total_deferred_count,
               qns        = qns        + v_total_qns_count,
               drive_date = cur_drive.start_time,
               mod_date   = sysdate,
               intent     = cur_intent.hema_intent_id,
               aph        = v_maph_drive
         where drive_id = cur_drive.drive_id
           and procedure_id = cur_proc_code.procedure_code_id
           and intent = cur_intent.hema_intent_id;
        commit;

     elsif v_existing_drive = 0 and v_total_registration_count > 0 then
      insert into hema_nightly
        (drive_id,
         procedure_id,
         performed,
         collected,
         registered,
         deferrals,
         qns,
         drive_date,
         mod_date,
         intent,
         aph)
      values
        (cur_drive.drive_id,
         cur_proc_code.procedure_code_id,
         v_total_performed_count,
         v_total_collected_count,
         v_total_registration_count,
         v_total_deferred_count,
         v_total_qns_count,
         trunc(cur_drive.start_time),
         sysdate,
         cur_intent.hema_intent_id,
         v_maph_drive);
      commit;
     end if;

    v_existing_drive := 0;

  end loop;
 end loop;
end loop;

end hema_drive_auto;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Views don't perform DML (insert, update, delete) and they don't manage transactions with COMMIT and ROLLBACK; they only select and retrieve data.